# Apollo Client 2 doesn't seem to handle local state management

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, apollo-client

We are currently struggling using Apollo Client to manage local state in a react application. We were able to build up a very simple example where we just display a div depending on the result of a mutation. The effect of the mutation should only be to display an alert message and return nothing.

We have come up with the following very simple example code:

File index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { withClientState } from 'apollo-link-state';

import App from './App';

const resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    setData: (_, {myBool}) => {
      alert(myBool);
      return null;
    }
  }
};

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: withClientState({ resolvers })
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

File App.js:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { Mutation } from 'react-apollo';

class App extends Component {

  setData = () => {
    alert('setData is called');
    const SET_DATA = gql`
      mutation SetData($myBool: Boolean!) {
        setData(myBool: $myBool) @client
      }
    `;
    return (
      <Mutation mutation={SET_DATA} variables={{ myBool: true }}>
        {(_, { loading, error }) => (
          <div>
            {loading && <p>...loading...</p>}
            {error && <p>ERROR ! Try reloading.</p>}
          </div>
        )}
      </Mutation>
    );
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <h1>App</h1>
        {this.setData()}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Could someone please tell us why the alert method we call in the setData() resolver (from file index.js) isn't called upon page loading?